# Calling function every minute doesn't work with heroku webhook

Tags: python, heroku, aiogram

I have a telegram bot, deployed on heroku. I am trying to make it checking a website for new transactions on it every minute. Usually I am using somethng like this:

```
async def check(wait_for):
    print("Debug: check is awaited")
    while True:
        print("Debug: inside while")
        await asyncio.sleep(wait_for)
        print("after sleep")
        transactions = parsing()
```

The function I call

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(check(30))
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

The loop

And it is working. But if I replace `executor.start_polling` with webhook start code:

```
start_webhook(
    dispatcher=dp,
    webhook_path=WEBHOOK_PATH,
    on_startup=on_startup,
    on_shutdown=on_shutdown,
    skip_updates=True,
    host=WEBAPP_HOST,
    port=WEBAPP_PORT
)
```

Check function prints "Debug: check is awaited" and "Debug: inside while", then webhook starts and function stops working. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own start_webhook func like:

```
from aiogram.utils.executor import set_webhook
from aiogram.dispatcher.webhook import DEFAULT_ROUTE_NAME

def start_webhook(dispatcher, webhook_path, *, loop=None, skip_updates=None, on_startup=None, on_shutdown=None, check_ip=False, retry_after=None, route_name=DEFAULT_ROUTE_NAME, **kwargs):
    executor = set_webhook(dispatcher=dispatcher,
                           webhook_path=webhook_path,
                           loop=loop,
                           skip_updates=skip_updates,
                           on_startup=on_startup,
                           on_shutdown=on_shutdown,
                           check_ip=check_ip,
                           retry_after=retry_after,
                           route_name=route_name)
    executor.run_app(loop=loop, **kwargs)
```

and forward your 'loop' to 'start_webhook':

```
start_webhook(
    loop=loop,
    dispatcher=dp,
    webhook_path=WEBHOOK_PATH,
    on_startup=on_startup,
    on_shutdown=on_shutdown,
    skip_updates=True,
    host=WEBAPP_HOST,
    port=WEBAPP_PORT
)
```